# what is happening when using data.table with tail command

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

## Create the data.table DT

```
set.seed(1L)
DT <- data.table(A = rep(letters[2:1], each = 4L), 
                 B = rep(1:4, each = 2L), 
                 C = sample(8))
```

## Create the new data.table, DT2

```
DT2 <-DT[, .(C = cumsum(C)), by =.(A,B)]
```

## Select from DT2 the last two values from C while you group by A

```
DT2[, .(C = tail(C,2)), by = A]
  A C
1: b 4
2: b 9
3: a 2
4: a 8
```

Can anyone explain what is happening in the last command ? I am selecting 2 values using tail(C,2) but it is giving me 4 values ?

Comment: You are selecting two values per `by=` group.

Comment: not getting you . please explain. As per my knowledge we use by to group command . right ?

Comment: `DT[, j, by=A]` does `j` for each distinct value of `A`. You have two values of A (a and b). For each value of the grouping variable, `j` is computed and returned. `j=tail(C,2)` will return (up to) two rows for each `A`. I say "up to" since `tail(x, 2)` has length 1 if `x` has length 1. If you get to the "Aggregations" section in the first package vignette, I'm sure it'll seem more natural: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: ok. Going in this manner suppose I have data set named 'mydata' of 40 obs and 1:10 obs for say 'a' and 11:20 for 'b' and 21:30 for 'c' and 31:40 for 'd'. let call this variable alphabet.
So in this case If i use by = alphabet and tail(anyvariable,2) then it will give me total 8 values consisting 9,10,19,20,29,30,39,40. right?

Comment: Sure, sounds right to me.

Comment: please provide confirmation. I am going to fix it in my memory.

Comment: Please edit your example into your question and test it yourself. If you are satisfied with what you find, you can post it as an answer to your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @learner yep, please self-answer, or just delete the question if you prefer for some reason

Comment: Will try it and going to put the result and other obs.please wait for 24hrs. Right now in remote area.